# query does not give desired result

Tags: mysql, sql

```
update notification_rule_details nrd SET nrd.NRL_FIRE_DATE=nrl_next_fire_date,nrd.NRL_NEXT_FIRE_DATE=cal_next_fire_date where nrd.NRD_ID=nrl_id and (nrd.NRD_NRL_ID!=3 or nrd.NRD_NRL_ID!=4);
```

in above query i want to update nrd.NRL_FIRE_DATE & nrd.NRL_NEXT_FIRE_DATE if nrd.NRD_NRL_ID!=3 or nrd.NRD_NRL_ID!=4
but it also update fire date & next fire date for 3 & 4

Comment: it is because you put a condition that ID is either not 3 or 4, if it is 3, then Not 4 condition is true and using "OR" operater in either of condition been true it update where id is 3, same with ID 4, so you can use NOT IN as other answer or change OR to AND.

Comment: Tip: don't use `OR` with `NOT` in conditions. It will always return *true*. So use `AND` with `NOT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always true :

```
(nrd.NRD_NRL_ID!=3 or nrd.NRD_NRL_ID!=4)
```

You have a logic problem.

Maybe you wanted

```
and nrd.NRD_NRL_ID!=3 and nrd.NRD_NRL_ID!=4
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Not In:

```
update notification_rule_details nrd SET nrd.NRL_FIRE_DATE=nrl_next_fire_date,nrd.NRL_NEXT_FIRE_DATE=cal_next_fire_date where nrd.NRD_ID=nrl_id and nrd.NRD_NRL_ID Not In (3,4);
```

Comment: +1, remember to format your answer, so it is readable, see hims identical answer

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`NOT IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in) for the that:

```
UPDATE notification_rule_details nrd 
SET nrd.NRL_FIRE_DATE=nrl_next_fire_date 
   ,nrd.NRL_NEXT_FIRE_DATE=cal_next_fire_date 
WHERE nrd.NRD_ID=nrl_id 
AND nrd.NRD_NRL_ID NOT IN(3,4);
```

#### See this sample [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93ed2/1)